# GUI SQL interface for select insert and remove

Tags: java, mysql, homework, swing, jdbc

This is my final project for my second Java class! I would like to get some feedback on it to see where and what I can improve.

There are five class files:

1. `GuiMusic`

   This contains all all of the the Swing and AWT components and the key listeners.
2. `ScrollPaneSync`

   Synchronizes the scroll bars on each `JPanel`.
3. `Stringbillder`

   Manipulates result set data into a different form so that it can be set onto 
   `JTextField`s.
4. `SqlCon`

   Contains the connection and the methods for sending queries.
5. `UpdateQuery`

   This is another data manipulation class used for insert and delete queries.

---

#### `GuiMusic`

I'm open to any critisim such that it's constructive but I have some specific questions

- How would you split the class to make it smaller?
- A lot of the `ActionListeners` have very similiar functionality, is it better to reuse them with different sources and expand the class or should everything have its own listener?

  I avoided some code repetition but I'm not sure that that's a good thing when you it might slow your program down.
- Could generics improve the flexibility of my code?

```
package guiMusic;


public class GuiMusic extends JFrame 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * @conn
     * object represents the connection to the database
     */
    SqlCon conn;
    /**
     * @stmt
     * used by conn to process sql query results
     */
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    /**
     * @sb
     * StringBuilder used to manipulate query data
     */
    StringBillder sb;
    /**
     * @formatedData
     * used to store information from textAreas and pass to conn
     */
    StringBuilder[] formatedData;
    /**
     * @addInfo
     * after a query from the add tab things are the information is stored in addinfo
     */
    String[] addInfo;
    /**
     * @sync
     * class that synchronizes scrollbars together
     */
    ScrollPaneSync sync;
    /**
     * @query
     * pretty self explanatory 
     */
    String query;

    /**
     * @search
     * @searchBar
     * @searchLabel
     * @searchText
     * majority of the objects needed for 
     * the creation of the search panel
     */
    JPanel search;
    JTextField searchBar;
    JTextField[] searchLabel = new JTextField[4];
    JTextArea[] searchText = new JTextArea[4];


    Font tmu = new Font("Tibetan Machine Uni",1, 20);
    Font tmus = new Font("Tibetan Machine Uni",1,15);
    String[] labelQueries= {
            "select * from info where %s like '%%%s%%'",
            "select * from info where %s like '%%%s%%' && %s like '%%%s%%'",
            "select * from info where %s like '%%%s%%' && %s like '%%%s%%' && %s like '%%%s%%'",
            "select * from info where %s like '%%%s%%' && %s like '%%%s%%' && %s like '%%%s%%' && %s like '%%%s%%'"};

    /**
     * @add
     * @addSubmit
     * @addClear
     * @addSearch
     * @addLabel
     * @addText
     * majority of objects needed for 
     * the creation of add panel
     */
    JPanel add;
    JButton addSubmit;
    JButton addClear;
    JTextField addSearch;
    JTextField[] addLabel = new JTextField[3];
    JTextArea[] addText = new JTextArea[3];
    /**
     * @remove
     * @remSubmit
     * @remClear
     * @remSearch
     * @remLabel
     * @remText
     * components needed for creation of 
     * the  remove tab
     */
    JPanel remove;
    JButton remSubmit;
    JButton remClear;
    JTextField remSearch;
    JTextField[] remLabel = new JTextField[4];
    JTextArea[] remText = new JTextArea[4];
    /**
     * @labelValues
     * used throughout program to make associations
     * and assign values
     * 
     */
    public final String[] LABELVALUES = {"artist" ,"album" ,"song", "genre"};


    GuiMusic() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        formatedData = new StringBuilder[4];

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            formatedData[i] = new StringBuilder();
        }

        addInfo = new String[4];
        conn = new SqlCon();
        sb = new StringBillder();

        setBounds(200, 100, 1500, 900);
        JTabbedPane main = new JTabbedPane();
        add(main);
        main.setFont(tmu);

        main.addTab("<html><body marginwidth=200 marginheight=10>Search</body></html>", createSearch());
        main.addTab("<html><body marginwidth=200 marginheight=10>Add</body></html>", createAdd());
        main.addTab("<html><body marginwidth=200 marginheight=10>Remove</body></html>", createRemove());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new WindowListener(){
            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.clothes();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
            }
            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
        }); 
    }

    private JPanel createSearch() 
    {
        search = new JPanel();  
        searchBar = new JTextField("search");
        searchBar.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        searchBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300,60));
        searchBar.setFont(tmu); 
        searchBar.setName("searchBar");
        searchBar.addKeyListener(new SearchBarListener());
        search.add(searchBar);
        JScrollPane[] scroll = new JScrollPane[4];

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            searchLabel[i] = new JTextField(LABELVALUES[i], SwingConstants.CENTER);
            searchLabel[i].setFont(tmu);
            searchLabel[i].setName(LABELVALUES[i]);
            searchLabel[i].addKeyListener( new textFieldListener());
            searchLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            searchLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,60));
            searchText[i] = new JTextArea();
            searchText[i].setFont(tmus);            
        }

        for(JTextField el : searchLabel)
        {
            search.add(el);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            scroll[i] = new JScrollPane(searchText[i]);
            scroll[i].setVerticalScrollBar(new JScrollBar());
            scroll[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,600));
            search.add(scroll[i]);  
        }
        sync = new ScrollPaneSync(scroll);
        for(int i = 0; i<scroll.length; i++)
        {
            scroll[i].getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(sync);
        }
        return search;      
    }

    private JPanel createAdd()
    {
        add = new JPanel();
        add.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        addClear = new JButton(("Clear"));
        addClear.setFont(tmu);
        addClear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,60));
        addClear.setName("addClear");
        addClear.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

        addSubmit = new JButton(("Submit"));
        addSubmit.setFont(tmu);
        addSubmit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,60));
        addSubmit.setName("addSubmit");
        addSubmit.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

        addSearch = new JTextField("Artist");
        addSearch.setFont(tmu);
        addSearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,60));
        addSearch.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        addSearch.setName("addSearch");
        addSearch.addKeyListener(new addSearchListener());

        add.add(addSubmit);
        add.add(addSearch);
        add.add(addClear);
        JScrollPane[] addScroll = new JScrollPane[3];

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            addLabel[i] = new JTextField(LABELVALUES[i+1]);
            addLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            addLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,100));
            addLabel[i].setFont(tmu);
            addLabel[i].setName(LABELVALUES[i+1]);
            addLabel[i].addKeyListener(new addFieldListener());
            add.add(addLabel[i]);
            addText[i] = new JTextArea();
            addText[i].setFont(tmus);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            addScroll[i] = new JScrollPane(addText[i]);
            addScroll[i].setVerticalScrollBar(new JScrollBar());
            addScroll[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,500));
            add.add(addScroll[i]);  
        }

        sync = new ScrollPaneSync(addScroll);

        for(int i = 0; i<addScroll.length; i++)
        {   
            addScroll[i].getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(sync);
        }
        return add;     
    }

    private JPanel createRemove()
    {
        remove = new JPanel();
        remSubmit = new JButton("Remove");
        remSubmit.setFont(tmu);
        remSubmit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,60));
        remSubmit.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

        remSearch = new JTextField("Search Term",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        remSearch.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        remSearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,60));
        remSearch.setFont(tmu);
        remSearch.setName("remSearch");
        remSearch.addKeyListener(new remBarListener());

        remClear = new JButton("Clear");
        remClear.setFont(tmu);
        remClear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,60));
        remClear.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

        remove.add(remSubmit);
        remove.add(remSearch);
        remove.add(remClear);
        JScrollPane[] remScroll = new JScrollPane[4];

        for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
        {
            remLabel[i] = new JTextField(LABELVALUES[i]);
            remLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            remLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,100));
            remLabel[i].setName(LABELVALUES[i]);
            remLabel[i].setFont(tmu);
            remLabel[i].addKeyListener(new textFieldListener());
            remove.add(remLabel[i]);

            remText[i]= new JTextArea();
            remText[i].setFont(tmus);

            remScroll[i] = new JScrollPane(remText[i]);
            remScroll[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,600));  
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            remove.add(remScroll[i]);
        }

        sync = new ScrollPaneSync(remScroll);
        for(int i = 0; i<remScroll.length; i++)
        {
            remScroll[i].getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(sync);
        }
        return remove;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("indie");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("XO");
        }
        new GuiMusic().setVisible(true);        
    }

    public class SearchBarListener implements KeyListener
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            query = searchBar.getText();    
            query = String.format("select * from info where album like '%%%s%%' || artist like '%%%s%%' || song like '%%%s%%'|| genre like '%%%s%%'",query,query,query,query);
            try
            {

                rs = conn.sqlQuery(query);

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    formatedData[i].setLength(0);
                }
                formatedData = sb.formatData(rs);

            } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}
                searchText[0].setText(formatedData[0].toString());
                searchText[1].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
                searchText[2].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
                searchText[3].setText(formatedData[3].toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }

    public class remBarListener implements KeyListener
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {   
            query = remSearch.getText();            
            query = String.format("select * from info where album like '%%%s%%' || artist like '%%%s%%' || song like '%%%s%%'|| genre like '%%%s%%'",query,query,query,query);

            try
            {
                rs = conn.sqlQuery(query);      
                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    formatedData[i].setLength(0);
                }
                formatedData = sb.formatData(rs);

            } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}

                remText[0].setText(formatedData[0].toString());
                remText[1].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
                remText[2].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
                remText[3].setText(formatedData[3].toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }

    public class textFieldListener implements KeyListener
    {

        String queryLocation;
        boolean[] validTextonLabel = new boolean[4];
        String getText;
        int numberOfTrue = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> trueIndex = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean search = false;
        boolean remove = false;



        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            {
                if(e.getSource().equals(remLabel[i]) || e.getSource().equals(remSearch))
                {   
                    remove = !remove;
                    System.out.println("work");
                }
                else if(e.getSource().equals(searchLabel[i]))
                    search = !search;
            }

            for(int q = 0; q <4; q++)
            {
                if(search)
                {
                    getText = searchLabel[q].getText();
                }
                else if(remove)
                {
                    getText = remLabel[q].getText();
                }

                if(!(getText.equals(null)) && !(getText.equals(LABELVALUES[q])) && !(getText.equals("")) && !(getText.equals(" ")))
                {
                    validTextonLabel[q] = true;
                    addInfo[q] = getText;
                    trueIndex.add(q);
                    numberOfTrue++;
                }
            }       

            if(numberOfTrue == 4)
            {
                query = String.format(labelQueries[3],LABELVALUES[0],addInfo[0],LABELVALUES[1],addInfo[1],LABELVALUES[2],addInfo[2],LABELVALUES[3],addInfo[3]);
            }
            else if(numberOfTrue == 3 )
            {
                query = String.format(labelQueries[2],LABELVALUES[trueIndex.get(0)],addInfo[trueIndex.get(0)],LABELVALUES[trueIndex.get(1)],addInfo[trueIndex.get(1)],LABELVALUES[trueIndex.get(2)],addInfo[trueIndex.get(2)]);
            }
            else if(numberOfTrue == 2)
            {
                query = String.format(labelQueries[1], LABELVALUES[trueIndex.get(0)],addInfo[trueIndex.get(0)],LABELVALUES[trueIndex.get(1)],addInfo[trueIndex.get(1)]);    
            }
            else if(numberOfTrue == 1)
            {
                query = String.format(labelQueries[0], LABELVALUES[trueIndex.get(0)],addInfo[trueIndex.get(0)]);
            }
            else if(e.getSource().equals(remSearch))
            {
                System.out.println("true");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("false");
            System.out.println(query);
            try 
            {
                rs = conn.sqlQuery(query);

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    formatedData[i].setLength(0);
                }
                formatedData = sb.formatData(rs);

            } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}

            if(search)
            {
                searchText[0].setText(formatedData[0].toString());
                searchText[1].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
                searchText[2].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
                searchText[3].setText(formatedData[3].toString());
            }
            else if(remove);
            {
                remText[0].setText(formatedData[0].toString());
                remText[1].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
                remText[2].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
                remText[3].setText(formatedData[3].toString());
            }

            trueIndex.clear();
            numberOfTrue = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            {
                validTextonLabel[i] = false;
            }
            search = false;
            remove = false; 
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }

    public class addFieldListener implements KeyListener
    {

        String queryLocation;

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            queryLocation =  e.getComponent().getName();
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
            {
                if(queryLocation.equals(LABELVALUES[i+1]))
                {
                    query = String.format("select * from info where %s like '%%%s%%'",LABELVALUES[i+1],addLabel[i].getText());
                }
            }

            try 
            {
                rs = conn.sqlQuery(query);

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    formatedData[i].setLength(0);
                }
                formatedData = sb.formatData(rs);

            } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}

            addText[0].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
            addText[1].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
            addText[2].setText(formatedData[3].toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }

    public class addSearchListener implements KeyListener
    {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            query = addSearch.getText();
            query = String.format("select * from info where album like '%%%s%%' || artist like '%%%s%%' || song like '%%%s%%'|| genre like '%%%s%%'",query,query,query,query);

            try {
                rs = conn.sqlQuery(query);

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    formatedData[i].setLength(0);
                }
                formatedData = sb.formatData(rs);

            } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}

            addText[0].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
            addText[1].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
            addText[2].setText(formatedData[3].toString());


        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }

    public class buttonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        String[][] addReturn;
        UpdateQuery uq;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            if(ae.getSource().equals(addClear))
            {
                addSearch.setText("");
                for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    addText[i].setText("");
                }
            }
            else if(ae.getSource().equals(remClear))
            {
                remSearch.setText("");
                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    remText[i].setText("");
                }
            }
            else if(ae.getSource().equals(addSubmit))
            {
                addInfo[0] = addSearch.getText();
                for(int i = 1; i<4; i++)
                {
                    addInfo[i] = addText[i-1].getText();
                }

                uq = new UpdateQuery();
                addReturn = uq.sqlUpdate(addInfo);

                for(int i = 0; i< addReturn[1].length; i++)
                {
                    query = String.format("insert into info values('%s','%s','%s','%s')", addReturn[0][0],addReturn[1][i],addReturn[2][i],addReturn[3][i]);

                    try 
                    {
                        conn.executeUpdate(query);
                    } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
            else if(ae.getSource().equals(remSubmit))
            {       
                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    addInfo[i] = remText[i].getText();
                }

                uq = new UpdateQuery();
                addReturn = uq.sqlUpdate(addInfo);

                for(int i = 0; i< addReturn[1].length; i++)
                {
                    query = String.format("delete from info where song = '%s'",addReturn[2][i]);

                    try 
                    {   
                        conn.executeUpdate(query);  
                    } catch (SQLException ef) {ef.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `ScrollPaneSync`

- Readability?

```
package guiMusic;



public class ScrollPaneSync implements AdjustmentListener
{

    JScrollBar[] bars;
    ScrollPaneSync(JScrollPane...scrolls)
    {
        bars = new JScrollBar[scrolls.length];
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<scrolls.length; i++)
        {
            bars[count] = scrolls[i].getVerticalScrollBar();
            count++;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
    {
         JScrollBar scrollBar = (JScrollBar)e.getSource();  
        for(int i = 0; i< bars.length; i++)
        {
            bars[i].setValue(scrollBar.getValue());
        }

    }

    }
```

#### `StringBillder`

```
    class StringBillder {
    private StringBuilder[] theReturn;
    private ArrayList<String> artVals;
    private ArrayList<String> albVals;
    private ArrayList<String> traVals;
    private ArrayList<String> genVals;
    StringBillder()
    {
        theReturn = new StringBuilder[4];

        for(int i = 0; i< theReturn.length;i++)
        {
            theReturn[i] = new StringBuilder();
        }

        artVals = new ArrayList<>();
        albVals = new ArrayList<>();
        traVals = new ArrayList<>();
        genVals = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public StringBuilder[] formatData(ResultSet rs) 
    {
        artVals.clear();
        albVals.clear();
        traVals.clear();
        genVals.clear();

        try 
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                artVals.add(rs.getString(1));
                albVals.add(rs.getString(2));
                traVals.add(rs.getString(3));
                genVals.add(rs.getString(4));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        for(String el : artVals)
        {
            theReturn[0].append(el).append("\n");   
        }

        for(String el: albVals)
        {
            theReturn[1].append(el).append("\n");
        }

        for(String el : traVals)
        {
            theReturn[2].append(el).append("\n");
        }

        for(String el : genVals)
        {
            theReturn[3].append(el).append("\n");
        }

        return theReturn;
    }
}
```

#### `SqlCon`

```
public class SqlCon {

    private static final String dbClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://this.is.a.ip/music";
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    SqlCon() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
         Class.forName(dbClassName);
         Properties p = new Properties();
         p.put("user", "foo");
         p.put("password", "bar"); 
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p);


    }
    public void executeUpdate(String query) throws SQLException
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }

    public ResultSet sqlQuery(final String query) throws SQLException
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        return rs;  
    }
    public void clothes() throws SQLException
    {
        if(con != null )
            con.close();
        if(stmt != null)
            stmt.close();
        if(rs != null)
            rs.close();
    }

}
```

#### `UpdateQuery`

```
public class UpdateQuery 
{


    String[][] formattedReturn;
    String[] queriedInfo;

    UpdateQuery()
    {   
        queriedInfo = new String[4];
        formattedReturn = new String[4][];
    }

    public String[][] sqlUpdate(String[] arg)
    {
        queriedInfo = arg;

        for(int column = 0; column<4;column++)
        {
            formattedReturn[column] = queriedInfo[column].split("\\n");
        }



        return formattedReturn;

    }
}
```

Comment: I often tell people to not name variables like i,j,k .... but if i see a JTextField-Variable having the name `addLabel`, i think i,j,k would be a better start. Finally i decide not to answer because it would be Sisyphean labor.

Comment: Is the misspelling `StringBillder` *intentional* so that it doesn't conflict with that of [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)? I think you need a much better class name here...

Comment: yes it is intentional, yeah it could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

## Code duplication

You have a lot of similar code blocks that set the following properties:

```
addClear.setFont(tmu);
addClear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,60));
addClear.setName("addClear");
```

You can consider extracting these out to a method that you can reuse:

```
private static <T extends JComponent> T setup(T component, String name, Font font, 
                                            int preferredWidth, int preferredHeight) {
    component.setName(name);
    component.setFont(font);
    component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredHeight));
    return component;
}
```

The idea of `return`-ing the `component` is to let you daisy-chain this method with calling other properties of the `component` itself, e.g.

```
// note: capital 'B' for ButtonListener
setup(addClear, "addClear", tmu, 220, 60).addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

## Collections vs arrays, and iterating through them

You seem to rely *a lot* on plain arrays... but I think one should tend towards the `Collection` classes as they are more *descriptive* in what their identity, e.g. a `Set` tells you that elements are distinct, and a `List` implies an ordering. Regardless of which you choose, you can already use the enhanced `for-each` loop (since *Java 1.5*) instead of the index-based `for`-loop, especially since you do not use the index:

```
for (JTextField textField : searchLabel) {
    // ...
}
```

**edit:** ah, so you did use these in your poorly-named `StringBillder`, but I'm not too sure how that is being used in the first place, and whether it is appropriate. For starters, you should declare your variables as `List<T> list = new ArrayList<>()`, instead of `ArrayList<T> list = ...`. This is because users of the `list` instance only needs to understand they are dealing with the `List` interface.

## Bracing style

The good news here is that your bracing style, while non-Java-conventional, is largely consistent. The only two exceptions I see are for your `catch` statements in `try-catch` blocks and the final `else`/`else if` clauses, so you may wish to improve on that.

Oh, and hang on for a moment, inside `textFieldListener.keyReleased(KeyEvent)`...

```
    else if(remove);
    {
        remText[0].setText(formatedData[0].toString());
        remText[1].setText(formatedData[1].toString());
        remText[2].setText(formatedData[2].toString());
        remText[3].setText(formatedData[3].toString());
    }
```

There is a ***bug*** here, I'll let you figure it out `;)`.

## Names

Your `*Listener` implementations should be using `PascalCase` for the class name too. Your arrays are better off in the plural forms, as it reads (or sounds) better that you are iterating through `searchLabels` than (a) `searchLabel`.

> Is the misspelling `StringBillder` *intentional* so that it doesn't conflict with that of [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)? I think you need a much better class name here... - [*myself*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99030/gui-sql-interface-for-select-insert-and-remove/105381#comment181570_99030)

And yeah, this earlier comment applies too.

## SQL and prepared statements

Initially, I was wondering why does your query template/patterns have so many `%`-s in them, before I realized they are used for `String.format(String, Object...)` as placeholders and to escape the literal `%` character.

The thing is, prepared statements for SQL queries are the way to go, and we don't mean literally preparing them using `String.format()`. I'll suggest [reading the documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information on this topic. :)